# Connecting to an MongoDb from webpage anonymously — finding the DSN

Tags: mongodb, realm, atlas

I am trying to connect to MongDB via Atlas Realm from a web-page.  The instructions, of course, make it look easy, saying you should do this:

```
const mongo = app.currentUser.mongoClient(DATA_SOURCE_NAME);
```

They just don’t tell you want your Datasource name *is*.

Much futzing around suggested I could use the following as an DSN:

`mongodb://_:${apiKey}@us-west-2.aws.realm.mongodb.com:27020/?authMechanism=PLAIN&authSource=%24external&ssl=true&appName=my-app-name:mongodb-atlas:api-key`

All I need know is the api-key.  Even more futzing around suggested I could use the following:

```
const apiKey = await user.apiKeys.create("abc");
```

But that gives me a 403.

Obviously, if I cannot use Mongo to *retrieve data*, it’s not very useful...

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about what you're trying to do? I am sure you've seen it but but there's a full [Web SDK](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/web/install/) guide. Also, the question is tagged Realm but it doesn't look like a question involves Realm - it sounds more just like Atlas? Also are you seeing this `const mongo = app.currentUser.mongoClient(DATA_SOURCE_NAME);` in the Realm SDK Docs? Perhaps it's the MongoClient docs? Just trying to help here and get some valid datapoints for you. Oh - the user api key is generated from the MongoDB Realm console website.

Comment: @Jay — I have the simplest possible use case: there is a Mongo DB linked to my Altas app; I want to read from it.  The boundaries between “Atlas”, “Realm”, and “Mongo” are unclear to me, to say the least.

Comment: lol. I totally understand that confusion. So, MongoDB is the company name and they have lots of technologies. One of the back end services is called Atlas which is a NoSQL Document database. One of the ways to work with Atlas data is called Realm - it's a suite of SDK's for end user devices; and there are SDK's for Swift, node.js, flutter, java, android and web. You can ALSO work within the SDK's to work with Atlas at a lower level - hitting url endpoints directly for example, but that bypasses much of the flexibility offered within the SDK's. Realm is also a local-first database, sync later.

Comment: So the question is this: do you want to work with an SDK to access Atlas data? Or do you want to work at a lower level, using CRUD operation or hitting endpoints and calling server functions? [Intro to MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/introduction/) is a good read. Also, [Intro to Realm](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/introduction/) and then probably what you want [Access Data with REST API](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/) which has info about authentication as well.

Comment: Forgot to answer your question... for this `mongoClient(DATA_SOURCE_NAME);` `DATA_SOURCE_NAME` is "mongodb-atlas" which is the cluster service name - that resolves to `const client = app.currentUser.mongoClient("mongodb-atlas")` you then need to specify the database and collection names.

Comment: @Jay — and I forgot to re-answer _your_ question.  I am trying to access the data from a web-page, ideally using “the SDK”, which I now think means the “Realm Web SDK”.

Comment: You got it! Go through [Web SDK Quick start](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/web/quickstart/) and that should get you up and running pretty quickly. Navigating the console is probably the most complex part but once you become familiar with it - things will go smoothly.